# Laravel 5.2 namespaces

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces

I am struggling with namespacing in laravel. I have a standard folder structure for a project after doing laravel new. I added a folder called dataaccess in the app folder so I put all my data access classes in so it has the following structure:

projectdir>app>dataaccess>dataaccessclasses(files)

and all my dataaccess classes have the namespace App at the top of every class ( I did this just to make things simple). Now in my controller I add this to the top so I can use my dataaccess classes:

```
<?php use App; ?>
```

But Laravel tells me that it cannot locate my dataaccess class and tries to resolve it relative to the namespace of the controller. Here is the error it spits at me:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 794: Class
>   App\Http\Controllers\StockDataAccess does not exist.

can any one shed any light on what all this means?

Answer (score 1):

The `app` folder by default follows [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) autoload specifications

so, when declaring  classes  in subfolders of your `app` folder, you shouldn't use the `App` namespace, but the namespace relative to the path of the specific subfolder.

For example, for in this class:

```
app > dataaccess > dataaccessclasses > StockDataAccess.php
```

you should use:

```
namespace App\dataaccess\dataaccessclasses\StockDataAccess;
```

in your class definition file. To use the class in the controller you should use:

```
use App\dataaccess\dataaccessclasses\StockDataAccess;
```

Comment: Tried this just as you said it and it still ends up with the same error. I am reading about psr-4 to understand what all this means but sadly, she ain't working

Comment: @Eagletrophy :  It gives you the same error? If you use `use App\dataaccess\dataaccessclasses\StockDataAccess;` in your controller, at least it should look for the class in that directory, giving you another error. For the PSR-4, as an example look at the existing Laravel classes inside the app folder (i.e, http/middleware ecc. ): you'll see that the namespace of every class depends always on the class file path

Comment: I checked what I have against what you just explained and I still am getting the same thing. This is really frustrating, because even after going through the PSR-4 document with php-fig, I still don't see where my error is. I will just write my data access code inside my controllers and forget about doing it this way. But this feels like a laravel bug to me not being able to correctly resolve paths in windows or something. Anyways Thanks for your help moppo

Comment: @Eagletrophy : try to post your class and controller code, along with the full path of the classes

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the classmap in composer.json 
with "app\dataaccess\dataaccessclasses" and run composer dump